# ASPX code behind ViewState not saving

Tags: asp.net, postback, viewstate

I am trying to use ViewState to retain my textbox's input during a postback.  Here's the code:

```
 private Label store_Incident_Number = new Label();
 private TextBox Incident_Number = new TextBox();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ViewState["Incident_Number"] != null)
        {                
            store_Incident_Number.Text = "TEST" + (string)ViewState["Incident_Number"];
            Panel1.Controls.Add(store_Incident_Number);
        }
    }

    void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ViewState.Add("Incident_Number", Incident_Number.Text);

    }
```

above code located in my default.aspx.cs (code behind).  The `Panel1` is an asp control some where on the web page outside of a form tag.  I am trying to follow this example:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227551(v=vs.85).aspx

I was hoping the Incident_Number textbox's text is saved onto the label after the page is postback, but it doesn't seems to work and I couldn't figure out the problem.  Note that the textbox is dynamically added to the form of the page and is recreated every postback.  My question is how I code to retain the textbox's value after the page is being postback?

> EDIT:  Fixed!  Please see my accepted answer.  Also, any eventhandler
>   or other process that have potential to trigger another postback
>   during Page_Init will refresh your value saved in viewstate (i.e. saved text is gone).

Comment: I think you are working harder than you need to. If you are using controls in an ASP.NET WebForms environment, many, including TextBox, have automatic viewstate management as long as you handle the page lifecycle correctly. Add the TextBox to the form in the Page_Init event then its viewstate will automatically be restored before the Page_Load event occurs (assuming it has the same ID each time) so the text entered by the user will be maintained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you're not letting the WebForms system work for you. Here's an example of a form with dynamically created controls maintaining viewstate. Per your description, the panel is outside the form.

When the page is displayed, you can enter new text and click submit repeatedly. The TextBox value will automatically be retained.

**Default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    </form>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
</body>
</html>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private Label store_Incident_Number = new Label();
    private TextBox Incident_Number = new TextBox() { ID = "TextBox1" };
    private Button SubmitButton = new Button() { ID = "Button1", Text = "Submit" };


    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // what is created during this event has viewstate restored to it
        Panel1.Controls.Add(store_Incident_Number);
        form1.Controls.Add(Incident_Number);
        form1.Controls.Add(SubmitButton);
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // the viewstate has already been restored so you can access the content of the TextBox
        store_Incident_Number.Text = Incident_Number.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Here's my question - The dynamic control needs to be present on the page after the postback in order for viewstate to save/load its value? if that is correct, I actually have a new question on it but I would rather post again to avoid text wall.  It is about a dropdown list (that load diff controls) and a submit button, both trigger postback.

Comment: I am running out of time here, I will post it first thing int he morning tomorrow, thanks user2638401

Comment: Yes. After the Page_Init event is complete, any controls on the page (whether static in the ASPX file or dynamically added during Page_Init) that have viewstate are restored (or updated if the user changed something with the latest post). So you build the _structure_ of the page during Page_Init and handle the _content_ of the controls during Page_Load.

Comment: I have a feeling this is gonna work.  I will let you know as soon as I updated my codes.  Thanks!!!

Comment: it works!  To fill you with information, I have an event handler during Page_Init and it actually cause error (another postback?) which remove the values saved in viewstate.

Comment: @Lidaranis touched on this briefly -  you should look into the page lifecycle more. When you have controls set to initiate a postback (e.g. a dropdown list set with autopostback=true) the Page_Init and Page_Load events are going to be called first before any events you attach to the control are called.

Comment: @user26374012 yes, I have review the lifecycle a bit after seeing Lidaranis's answer.  The thing that keeps me away from the solution is the diff between Page_load and Page_Init, otherwise the whole picture make sense to me

Comment: If you think about it in terms of a DOM (Document Object Model) similar to the DOM in your web browser, the Page_Init event is where you can add new controls. Then, before the Page_Load event occurs, two things happen: 1) any viewstate associated with an ID of a control you added is restored. 2) data changes the user entered are applied. Then the Page_Load event is called and you can interrogate your control values to use user-submitted data. Or you can do that within the event handler for the specific control that triggered the postback. Either way

Answer (score 2):

That happens because the page load method runs before the prerender. You can Google asp.net page lifecicle to find more details.

What you are basically doing here is loading the label value before adding it in the viewstate.

Also, it would help if you could tell us how exactly are you making the postback. Because click events for example, are also a part of the page lifecicle and that might change a few things.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought I know the the page life cycle, apparently I am not.  How should this be done?  Also I will update my post to include how postback is done.

Comment: Also I was trying to follow the this example:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227551(v=vs.85).aspx